# Create Folders Based On Unique Identifier In File Name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

I am in need of some assistance.Have been searching online including this forum but have been unable to find a solution thus far.

I have many thousands of images which I want to move into folders based on a unique identifier in the file names. They all have the same structure as follows:

```
ID - 1234 - blahblahblah - 0001234.jpeg
ID - 1234 - blahblahblah - 0001235.jpeg
ID - 1234 - blahblahblah - 0001236.jpeg
ID - 2345 - bloobloobloo - 0001234.jpeg
ID - 2345 - bloobloobloo - 0001235.jpeg
ID - 2345 - bloobloobloo - 0001236.jpeg
ID - 3456 - bleebleeblee - 0001234.jpeg
ID - 3456 - bleebleeblee - 0001235.jpeg
ID - 3456 - bleebleeblee - 0001236.jpeg
```

I want to move all of the above files into the following folders (in this case, three files in each folder)

```
ID - 1234 - blahblahblah
ID - 2345 - bloobloobloo
ID - 3456 - bleebleeblee
```

I understand that I can shift and right click on the parent folder where these images are stored and run a cmd command. I have used this to batch rename but am struggling to move the files.

The next step would be to print all files in each folder as one pdf (I have a pdf printer that can achieve this) which would essentially create a catalogue of each folder.

I hope you can help me :-)

Many thanks,
Manpaal Singh

Comment: Start with splitting the name of the file, then detect the name of the folder this file should be and just move it creating directory if needed. I personally would prefer doing this in python

Comment: `ID - 1234 - blahblahblah` will contain 3 files called... `0001234.jpeg` or called `ID - 1234 - blahblahblah - 0001234.jpeg`?

Comment: What have you tried on your own so far? what part do you have problems with?

Comment: Your sample data contains a duplicate line (unintentionally, I guess)... What part of the file name should be checked for uniqueness: all `ID - 1234 - blahblahblah - `, or only the numeric `1234` part?

Answer (score 2):

If you feel like installing `awk/gawk` for Windows from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm), you can do it quite easily.

Generate a list of your files like the one in your question using

```
DIR /B *.jpeg > files.txt
```

Then use this `awk` script:

```
awk -F" - " '{dir=$1 " - " $2 " - " $3; file=$4; printf "MKDIR \"%s\"\n",dir; printf "COPY \"%s\" \"%s\\%s\"\n",$0,dir,file}' files.txt
```

and it will generate output like this:

```
MKDIR "ID - 1234 - blahblahblah"
COPY "ID - 1234 - blahblahblah - 0001234.jpeg" "ID - 1234 - blahblahblah\0001234.jpeg"
MKDIR "ID - 1234 - blahblahblah"
COPY "ID - 1234 - blahblahblah - 0001235.jpeg" "ID - 1234 - blahblahblah\0001235.jpeg"
MKDIR "ID - 1234 - blahblahblah"
COPY "ID - 1234 - blahblahblah - 0001236.jpeg" "ID - 1234 - blahblahblah\0001236.jpeg"
MKDIR "ID - 2345 - bloobloobloo"
COPY "ID - 2345 - bloobloobloo - 0001234.jpeg" "ID - 2345 - bloobloobloo\0001234.jpeg"
MKDIR "ID - 2345 - bloobloobloo"
COPY "ID - 2345 - bloobloobloo - 0001235.jpeg" "ID - 2345 - bloobloobloo\0001235.jpeg"
MKDIR "ID - 2345 - bloobloobloo"
COPY "ID - 2345 - bloobloobloo - 0001236.jpeg" "ID - 2345 - bloobloobloo\0001236.jpeg"
MKDIR "ID - 3456 - bleebleeblee"
COPY "ID - 3456 - bleebleeblee - 0001234.jpeg" "ID - 3456 - bleebleeblee\0001234.jpeg"
MKDIR "ID - 3456 - bleebleeblee"
COPY "ID - 3456 - bleebleeblee - 0001235.jpeg" "ID - 3456 - bleebleeblee\0001235.jpeg"
MKDIR "ID - 3456 - bleebleeblee"
COPY "ID - 3456 - bleebleeblee - 0001236.jpeg" "ID - 3456 - bleebleeblee\0001236.jpeg"
MKDIR "ID - 3456 - bleebleeblee"
COPY "ID - 3456 - bleebleeblee - 0001236.jpeg" "ID - 3456 - bleebleeblee\0001236.jpeg"
```

which you can save in a BATCH file and then run if you like it. At the moment, of course, it does nothing except show what it would do.

To explain the command:

- -F" - " says to split the fields on each line by a space followed by a dash and a space, so $1 will be your ID, $2 will be the number, $3 will be "blahblahblah", $4 will be the JPEG filename
- dir will hold just the name of the output directory
- file will hold just the filename

On Windows, the quoting on the command-line is difficult, so it is easier to put the script into a file which `awk` looks in, rather than hoping Windows can work out and understand single and double quotes. So, you would save the following in a file called `script.awk`

```
{
  dir=$1 " - " $2 " - " $3                       # Extract directory
  file=$4                                        # Extract filename
  printf "MKDIR \"%s\"\n",dir                    # Create outout directory
  printf "COPY \"%s\" \"%s\\%s\"\n",$0,dir,file  # Copy file to directory
}
```

and run it with

```
awk -F" - " -f script.awk files.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Supposing the (first) numeric part of the file names always consists of four digits and the working directory is the one containing the `*.jpeg` files, the following code should work for you:

```
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B "ID - ???? - * - *.jpeg"
') do (
    for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=- " %%I in ("%%~F") do (
        > nul 2>&1 md "%%I - %%J - %%K"
        move /Y "%%~F" "%%I - %%J - %%K\%%~F"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The directory name can be gathered by using the substring capabilities of `cmd`. I cannot imagine that the file names are always this rigorously formatted, but that is what is in the question. There should be error checking added for the directory creation and move operations.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f IN (`DIR /B "ID -*.jpeg"`) DO (
    SET FNAME=%%~f
    SET DNAME=!FNAME:~0,24!

    IF NOT EXIST "!DNAME!" (MKDIR "!DNAME!")
    MOVE /Y "!FNAME!" "!DNAME!" >NUL
)

EXIT /B 0
```